# Program adjust transparent image for greenscreen

Tags: java, color-key

as a fun little project, I am trying to create an 'overlay' program. 
Perhaps you've heard of the program 'open broadcaster software'. 
This is a streaming program that can 'record' windows and apply 'color key' to them (making a certain color transparent)

I have a program that creates a window with a green background, acting as the greenscreen. On this window I want to make images appear, dissapear and move.

So far so good, however the problem comes with transparent images. They have a color hue over them because the color key tries to remove or smoothen out the colors.

So my question is; is there a way to programmatically add a color to a picture, or strengthen other colors, so color key would instead render the original?

Sincerely,
JB

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a pertially translucent image on a backgroud showing the background color shining trough is the whole *point* of translucency.

There is nothing you can do without sacrificing the transparency in some way or another. A few useful effects can be achieved with java.awt.AlphaComposite, but I'm not sure any of the effects suit your fancy.

You could preprocess the images and change translucency to simple transparent/opaque (e.g. alter alpha for each pixel to `newAlpha = oldAlpha < threshHold ? 0x00 : 0xFF`). Selecting a good-looking threshhold value might be tricky (no one-size fits all). Needless to say that this will result in a drop in perceived image quality.